# Create logs in perl

Tags: perl

I have many subroutines in my perl script. I want to create log for each subroutine i.e. log will write whether subroutine worked fine or if failed then where it is failed. As per my logic flag should be maintained & if based on flag value subroutine log is created. I am new to perl so can anyone give me an example for the same.

Comment: You need to read this first and think about posting this kind of question. http://oreilly.com/catalog/lperl3/chapter/ch04.html

Comment: This sounds like a trace file for debugging.

Comment: Yes, motive behind creating this is user will directly look into logs for errors

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are trying to do can be either achieved by manually inserting logging statements:

```
use constant LOG => 1;

sub foo {
  debug 'BEFORE', 'main::foo', @_ if LOG; # gets optimized away if LOG is false
  do stuff;
  debug 'AFTER', 'main::foo', if LOG;      # the same
  return $things;
}
```

(assuming `debug` is a function that does the logging)

However, we can automate that for certain cases. Especially, we can add logging wrappers for every *named* subroutine. We will do this as metaprogramming via the *package stash*, which is the symbol table.

A stash is a big hash with names like `%main::`, note the trailing double colon. It holds *globs*, which are hashes with a fixed set of keys. They have the `*` sigil. The `CODE` entry of a glob holds a code reference.

We can select all globs of a stash that hold code entries like

```
my $stash = \%main::;
my @interesting_globs = grep *$_{CODE}, values %$stash;
```

We can assign a reference to a glob, this will populate the correct slot in the glob. For example,

```
sub foo { say 1 }
```

is roughly the same thing as

```
BEGIN {
  *foo = sub { say 1 };
}
```

So now we can wrap the original sub with a wrapper that does the logging:

```
for my $glob (@interesting_globs) {
  my $code = *$glob{CODE}; # store the coderef in a lexical variable
  no warnings 'redefine';
  *$glob = sub {
     debug 'BEFORE', $glob, @_ if LOG;
     my @return_value = wantarray ? &$code : scalar &$code;
     debug 'AFTER', $glob, @return_value if LOG;
     return wantarray ? @return_value : $return_value[0];
  }
}
```

The `wantarray` stuff makes sure that the inner sub is called in correct context (list context/scalar context). However, we do not check for void context. The `&$code` (note the missing parens) is a fancy way of saying `$code->(@_)` or `&$code(@_)`.

It is imporant that the subs are decorated after all subs are compiled. Therefore, it should probably be executed inside an `INIT` block, which is run after the main compilation phase, but before regular execution begins.

There are a few drawbacks with this solution:

1. It only works on named subs, but not anonymous subs.
2. It also decorates imported subs by default.
3. Without further filters, it will decorate all subs.
4. We don't propagate void context to the original code.

A better solution would use *subroutine attributes*, but they are a bit difficult to set up.  Attributes are handlers that are executed upon compilation and can convey metadata. E.g. in `sub foo :log_this { ... }`, the `log_this` handler would be called.

---

Complete example:

```
$ perl -E'
  sub foo {say "@_"};
  sub bar { foo(0, @_, "inf") }
  INIT{
    for my $glob (grep *$_{CODE}, values %main::){
      my $orig = *$glob{CODE};
      *$glob = sub {
        say "BEFORE $glob: @_";
        my @ret = $orig->(@_); # this demo misses context handling
        say "AFTER $glob: @ret";
        @ret;
      };
    }
  }
  bar(1,2,3)'
BEFORE *main::bar: 1 2 3
BEFORE *main::foo: 0 1 2 3 inf
0 1 2 3 inf
AFTER *main::foo: 1
AFTER *main::bar: 1
```

Answer (score 2):

The most straight forward solution is just writing a `debug` subroutine and use it where appropriate:

```
sub debug {
    my($p, $f, $l) = caller;
    print "$p, $f, $l\n";
}

sub test {
    debug;
    print "something\n";
    debug;
}
```

You can look up `caller` on the `perlfunc` man page.

If you want it much more spiffy, take [Aspect](http://search.cpan.org/~adamk/Aspect-1.04/lib/Aspect.pm) for a spin.